# How to get all Azure Resources without tags in a Azure Resource Group excluding Hidden tags

Tags: azure, powershell, cloud, azure-resource-manager

I am able to filter the resources without tags using below script

Get-AzResource `| Where-Object {$null -eq $_.Tags -or $_.Tags.Count -eq 0}`
| Format-Table -AutoSize
but the problem it is including the hidden resources along with it.

My requirement is to filter the tags without hidden types.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-notlike`  comparison operator  to filter the tags without hidden types and run this PowerShell command:

`Get-AzResource | Where-Object {$_ -notlike "hidden-*" } | Format-Table -AutoSize`

You can refer to [Comparison operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.1#matching-operators), GitHub issue at [Hidden/Not Hidden flag for get-azresource](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/10365) and [Get-AzureRmResource - parameter for excluding hidden resources](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/9102)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is use Azure Graph explorer,
run this query,

```
resources
|where tags !has "your tag name"
```

//this will show the all the resource which does not have the tag with "your tag name"